# code contracts usage with exceptions

Tags: c#, exception

```
void ReadContent(string path)
{
  Contract.Requires(path!=null);
  string contentofileasstring = filehelperobj.GetContent(path);
   if(String.IsNullOrEmpty(contentofileasstring ))
  {
    throw new FileContentException(path + "No content found");
  }
  m_xmlobj = contentofileasstring ;
}
```

Is my assumption of the usage of code contracts and exceptions right in this case. Do you think it is logical to replace the exception with a code contract(or vice versa)?

code not tested.Just an example scenario

Comment: This code looks strange, check after use. Please clear that up.

Comment: After the edit, the error is slightly misleading. What if the file was found with the wrong (empty) content ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would probably go for an implementation which looks like the following:

```
private void ReadContent(string path)
{
    Contract.Requires<FileMissingException>(File.Exists(path));
    string content = filehelperobj.GetContent(path);
    m_xmlobj = content;
}
```

**Post Edit**

As it's the content you want to validate, I would put a `Contract.Ensures(!String.IsNullOrEmpty(Contract.Result<string>()));` inside the `filehelperobj.GetContent(string)` method. Then if the content being read was null or empty, I would throw an exception. e.g.

```
public string GetContent(string path)
{
    Contract.Requires<FileMissingException>(File.Exists(path));
    Contract.Ensures(!String.IsNullOrEmpty(Contract.Result<string>()));

    using(var reader = new StreamReader(File.OpenRead(path)))
    {
        var content = reader.ReadToEnd();

        if(String.IsNullOrEmpty(content))
            throw new FileContentException("No content found at file: " + path);

        return content;
    }
}
```

Comment: what if content is empty? That is the situation I am interested to find out(between usage of contract and exceptions).

Comment: @Jimmy Updated my answer in response to your edited question.

Answer (score 1):

Well assuming you had the lines the wrong way round (ie, test the path for null *before* trying to use it) then yes, it is a valid pre-condition and therefore should be a code contract.

Comment: I hope you read my edited post.How do you differentiate "valid" code contracts with "invalid" ones which probably needs to throw?